# Messaging and email intents in Android?

Tags: android, email, sms, android-intent

I've searched Google for this, but have only found similar examples--not exactly what I need. I simply need to start messaging (SMS) and email intents from my app with their "to" fields already populated. So I need to send a number with the sms intent and an email address with the email intent. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the e-mail part :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"foo@bar.com"});

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send a mail ..."));
```

Comment: You might also take a look to Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT and Intent.EXTRA_TEXT to fill the e-mail

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses. I noticed one thing though--when doing the SMS intent, setType() shouldn't be used because it will make the app chooser say that no apps can perform the action.

Comment: Yep, setType is used to know if you want to send through E-mail, facebook, twitter, ...

Comment: To clarify: The receivers look at the setType() value and will present themselves in the chooser dialog if they decide they can handle the specified type.  For example, on my device setType("text/html") prevents SMS apps from being an option, but setType("text/plain") does not.

Answer (score 1):

from [Only Email apps to resolve an Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506637/)

```
   String recepientEmail = ""; // either set to destination email or leave empty
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + recepientEmail));
   startActivity(intent);
```

will filter out all non-email applications.