# Android Mimic Auto-Link Intent for Email- Missing Address

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I was wondering how I can mimic the action that occurs on an auto-linked email address via an intent.  I tried using this method, [Messaging and email intents in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453490/messaging-and-email-intents-in-android/3453559#3453559) and ran in on my phone and in my emulator and the message window opened but did not have the email address.  And the composer window for the auto-link looks different than the composer for the following code.  Any ideas?

Here is the code from the link above so you dont have to click:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"foo@bar.com"});

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send a mail ..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a subject or body, which may be confusing the email client. Also, unless you specifically want the user to have to choose their mail client, skip the `createChooser()` and just call `startActivity(emailIntent)`, as that will bring up their default client. See [here](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlestrickssecrets/178-enabling-users-to-send-email-from-your-android-applications) for a blog post with more samples.