# Mail Intent doesn't show default Mail app

Tags: android, android-intent

On some phones (HTC Desire S with Gingerbread and Galaxy Nexus) the following intent does not start the default mail client (com.android.mail).

```
viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
viewIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

Is there any way to find out which intent can be used to start the default mai client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to change my intent to using a "mailto:" link instead of using intent extras to make it work on the HTC.

More details can be found here: [Only Email apps to resolve an Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506637/only-email-apps-to-resolve-an-intent)

Answer (score 4):

Email correct mime type is `message/rfc822`. `text/plain` should work too,  but may trigger other handlers. `plain/text` is incorrect.

Also, ACTION_SENDTO is better if you are passing email addresses as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but changing text/plain to message/rfc822 doesn't change anything. And there is no app that can handle the ACTION_SENDTO action (not even GMail seems to be registered for this)

Comment: weird. did you tried to see what intent is fired by application that are actually using the email app?

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               String toMail[] = {"email id"};
               emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,toMail);
               emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
               emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
               emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
               startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks, but even with the eMail extras the intent doesn't show the default mail activity.

Comment: if you are not getting any error then test it on device , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below :

```
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { email_add });
        startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Same as above, unfortunately it doesn't change anything