# Intent : remove Always / Only once buttons

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm pretty new to Android development.

Is it possible to remove the two buttons (Always / Only Once) when opening an `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` ?

Here is my current code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICK);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open in...");
startActivityForResult(openInChooser,PICK);
```

Comment: Best solution I found so far thanks ! Other people suggested creating a custom picker, which is obviously much more work. You should mark your own answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

That is a system generated dialog, so you cannot alter it.

You could use `queryIntentActivities()` to get a list of the apps which can respond to your intent, and then show them in your own dialog without the buttons if you like.

Comment: Or even launch the specific one you want.  But I would warn against that-  the list of installed apps varies by device and I would not assume something will be installed on any other model of phone.  But it can be good enough if you're writing the app for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to create an `Intent.createChooser()`,  if you call `Intent.createChooser()`, passing it your Intent object, it returns a version of your intent that will always display the chooser.
Example:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my awesome text to share.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"));
```